# Signed-in user claims missing under Profile page in ASP.NET Core Web App calling the Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net, azure-app-configuration, azure-identity

I have one single tenant application with redirect uri and front-channel logout url as https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc

I can authenticate to the application but after selecting profile, it is not displaying signed-in user claims instead throwing exceptions

```
ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
 Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync<T>(object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet_graph.Controllers.HomeController.Profile() in  `HomeController.cs`
currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

*appsettings.json*:

```json
{
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "*********.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "985b8469-9fa1-4c3c-916b-0aeaa612c42d",
"ClientId": "1577b22e-c888-4e44-8d2a-071650bf02a6",
"ClientSecret": "",
"ClientCertificates": [
],
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"DownstreamApi": {
"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
"Scopes": "openid profile"
},
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

*Startup.cs:*

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddRazorPages()
                  .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

I want signed-in user claims like profile photo, display name, Mail when Profile page is selected. Any pointers are really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I registered one single tenant Azure AD application and added Redirect & logout URLs **same** as you like below:

[image]

To get signed-in user profile, you need to add **`User.Read`** API permission like below:

[image]

I have one Azure AD user named `Sri Admin` whose properties are as below:

[image]

I cloned the sample from below reference and updated **`appsettings.json`** file like below:

```json
"Scopes": "user.read"
```

[image]

When I ran the code by entering **user credentials**, I got consent screen like below:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, user **signed in** successfully as below:

[image]

When I clicked **Profile** link on the top menu, I got signed-in **user claims** successfully as below:

[image]

In your case, add **`User.Read`** permission in your application and modify **scope** parameter in code accordingly like below:

```json
"Scopes": "user.read"
```

**Reference:** [ASP.NET Core Web App calling the Microsoft Graph - GitHub](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph)